# converting documentclasses into environments: is it possible?

Tags: formatting, environments, document-classes

Rewritten question. For my phd-project i need to quote screenplays. I would like to keep the screenplay layout in my thesis. I know there is the document class called `screenplay`.

Now i am wandering if it is generally possible to convert a document class into an "classic" environment, so that you can use all the useful stuff of one document class within another document class.

In my case I would like to write `\begin{screenplay}...\end{screenplay}` and include all the helpful devices from the screenplay document class within this environment. For example:

```
\begin{screenplay} 
\fadein 
\intslug[Tag]{Bantago Bay} 
... 
\end{screenplay}
```

Comment: No, classes aren't complex environments and can't be converted to one. You might however put the required code from this class to an environment, so that the format and macros are only used inside the environment.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Do i need to have an advanced knowledge of latex to do so?

Comment: @Philip The `screenplay` class isn't very complicated. The main thing you would need to do to adapt it to a package would be to remove all the titling and page layout stuff. So the core macros are from line 122 onwards, plus any of the lengths that are used in those commands (which are declared and set earlier in the code.). Do you feel comfortable around package code, or have you never looked inside one before?

Comment: @Alan Munn: To be honest, i even didnt hear about that things ever before. I guess that i wouldnt be able to cope with that task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a package version of the `screenplay` class that can be used within any document class.  It adds a new environment `screenplay` to wrap screenplay fragments in, and a couple of commands for customizing the font and spacing. (See the README file for details.) I have contacted the author of the `screenplay` class to see if he is interested in adding this to his distribution. If not, I will upload it to CTAN as a separate package.

### Update

The package is now available on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pgk/screenplay-pkg).

Comment: I'm adding this to the list of packages prompted by tex.sx questions on the blog!

Comment: I still try to figure out how to install the screenplay-pkg.sty. But your example file works. And i am looking forward to working with this package. So thank you very much for helping.

Comment: @Philip Look here: [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/2693); [How can I manually install a package on MikTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/2693)

Comment: @Alan Munn: Now I figured it out and it works. So, again: Thank you so much.