# screenplay-pkg affects margins

Tags: margins, screenplay

I am having a problem with the [`screenplay-pkg`](http://ctan.org/pkg/screenplay-pkg).

Just declaring it affects the size of the margins of left- and right edge & spine margins (about the size of 1 letter). If I comment it out, then the problem disappears. I tried this with the `book`-, `article`- and `memoir`-class.

They all showed the same problem. Any idea what I can do? I am typesetting a book with a few pages screenplay-typesetting.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{screenplay-pkg}
% with sreenplay-pkg --> margins (f.i. spine left-rightpage0 differ
% without screenplay-pkg   ----> margins equal

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `spine margins (about the size of 1 letter)` How to do actually determine this? It also helps to put a link to this package `{screenplay-pkg}` so that folks do not spend time looking for it since it is not on CTAN

Comment: The margins are wrong. I don't know how to bemore presize.

Comment: The packacke Ifound on: http://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/screenplay-pkg.zip

Comment: Hi, I realise that I claimed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26227/2693) that I would upload this version to CTAN, so I guess I am the *de facto* maintainer of the package version.  I'll look into this later today and add and answer (unless Nasser's answer is sufficient as a bug fix).  I then should get around to putting this up on CTAN too.

Comment: The package has now been added to CTAN.